# Compile pdfpages Code with LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, pdfpages

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper
]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newcount\firstmaxpages
\newcount\secondmaxpages
\newcount\curpage
\newcount\untilpage
\makeatletter
\newif\if@pdfdingsSecondFin
\newcount\@pdfdingsPages

\newcommand*\@incpdfdings[5][]{%
    \includepdf[
        nup = #5,
        pages = {#2-#3},
        #1
    ]{#4}}
\newcommand*\@@incpdfdings{}%
\def\@@incpdfdings#1x#2;{%
    \@pdfdingsPages=#1%
    \multiply\@pdfdingsPages by #2%
    \advance\@pdfdingsPages by -1%
}
\newcommand*\incpdfdings[4][]{%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax%
        \pdfximage{#3}%
        \firstmaxpages=\pdflastximagepages%
        \pdfximage{#4}%
        \secondmaxpages=\pdflastximagepages%
        \ifnum\firstmaxpages<\secondmaxpages%
            \@latex@error{incpdfdings: Fail!}{}%
        \fi%
    \else%
        \firstmaxpages=#1%
    \fi%
    \curpage=0%
    \@@incpdfdings#2;%
    \loop\ifnum\firstmaxpages>\curpage%
        \advance\curpage by 1%
        \untilpage=\numexpr\curpage+\@pdfdingsPages\relax%
        \ifnum\untilpage>\firstmaxpages%
            \untilpage=\firstmaxpages%
        \fi%
        \@incpdfdings[frame=true]{\the\curpage}{\the\untilpage}{#3}{#2}%
        \ifnum\secondmaxpages>\untilpage\else%
            \untilpage=\secondmaxpages%
        \fi%
        \if@pdfdingsSecondFin\else%
            \@incpdfdings{\the\curpage}{\the\untilpage}{#4}{#2}%
        \fi%
        \ifnum\secondmaxpages=\untilpage%
            \@pdfdingsSecondFintrue%
        \fi%
        \advance\curpage by \@pdfdingsPages%
    \repeat%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\incpdfdings{3x6}%
  {A.pdf}%
  {B.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Assume we have two PDF files named `A.pdf` and `B.pdf` in the same directory as the `.tex` file with the code above. If I compile the code using `pdflatex` everything is fine but if I compile using `lualatex`, I get the following error message:

```
\incpdfdings ...>\ifx \relax #1\relax \pdfximage 
                                                  {#3}\firstmaxpages =\pdfla...

l.68   {B.pdf}
```

**Question**

How do I change the code above so that I can compile it using the `lualatex` engine?

**Update**

I've tried to remove all the `%`s according to David's suggestion. Have I got it right?

```
\newcommand*\@incpdfdings[5][]{%
    \includepdf[
        nup = #5,
        pages = {#2-#3},
        #1
    ]{#4}}
\newcommand*\@@incpdfdings{}%
\def\@@incpdfdings#1x#2;{%
    \@pdfdingsPages=#1
    \multiply\@pdfdingsPages by #2
    \advance\@pdfdingsPages by -1
}
\newcommand*\incpdfdings[4][]{%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax
        \saveimageresource{#3}%
        \firstmaxpages=\lastsavedimageresourcepages
        \saveimageresource{#4}%
        \secondmaxpages=\lastsavedimageresourcepages
        \ifnum\firstmaxpages<\secondmaxpages
            \@latex@error{incpdfdings: Der er ikke nok forsider.}{}%
        \fi
    \else
        \firstmaxpages=#1
    \fi
    \curpage=0
    \@@incpdfdings#2;%
    \loop\ifnum\firstmaxpages>\curpage
        \advance\curpage by 1
        \untilpage=\numexpr\curpage+\@pdfdingsPages\relax
        \ifnum\untilpage>\firstmaxpages
            \untilpage=\firstmaxpages
        \fi
        \@incpdfdings[frame=true]{\the\curpage}{\the\untilpage}{#3}{#2}%
        \ifnum\secondmaxpages>\untilpage\else
            \untilpage=\secondmaxpages
        \fi
        \if@pdfdingsSecondFin\else
            \@incpdfdings{\the\curpage}{\the\untilpage}{#4}{#2}%
        \fi
        \ifnum\secondmaxpages=\untilpage
            \@pdfdingsSecondFintrue
        \fi
        \advance\curpage by \@pdfdingsPages
    \repeat
}
```

Comment: the l3graphics package has a command \graphics_get_pagecount:nn which works with all engines.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you very much. The code is not something that I've created myself and honestly I don't quite understand what is going on, so if I can make you ajust the code, I'll happily accept your answer.

Comment: don't use `%` like `\curpage=0% that will cause the following line to be expanded before the assignment.  probably the majority of `%` here are problematic, ones after commands do nothing, ones after literal digits do harm.

Comment: On page 44 of the LuaTeX manual, at the end of Section 3.1.4 "Changes from PDFTeX 1.40", there is a table of LuaTeX commands and equivalent pdfTeX commands. Your document probably works if you replace all the pdfTeX commands from that table with the LuaTeX commands.

Comment: You could use `\usepackage{luatex85}` which defines most of the pdftex names in terms of luatex primitives

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Thanks! After replacing the PDFTeX commands with the equivalent LuaTeX ones, it compiles just fine. `:-)`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can you tell me exactly which `%`s to remove and which ones to leave? As I said in the command to Ulrike, it is not my code, but I would very much like to get it right. `:-)` Thank you in advance.

Comment: as I said, remove every `%` that follows a command name or a digit.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. Is my added try in the question post correct?

Comment: looks good to me:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks alot! If you convert your comment(s) into an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `\usepackage{luatex85}` which defines most of the pdftex names in terms of luatex primitives.